# Regex Match word by being insensitive to Capital Letters

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the word `"regex"` in a given piece of text irrespective of capital letters.

`'I like regex a lot.'` should match.

`'I like REGEX a lot.'` should match.

`'I like Regex a lot.'` should match.

`'I like ReGeX a lot.'` should match.

`'I like RegeX a lot.'` should match.

`'I like regexa lot'` should not match.

`'I like regex22 lot'` should not match.

Comment: Use [`word boundaries`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and [`case insensitive flag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE), see this [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/Vrydck/2)

Comment: I don't see how it is a duplicate to the question tagged. That question talks about reading word boundaries. It does not mention case sensitiveness anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the word "regex" (case-insensitive) in a string, you can use this regex (in python you can use the `re.IGNORECASE` flag to make it case-insensitive):

```
.*\bregex\b.*
```

Example:

```
>>> re.match(r'.*\bregex\b.*', 'I like RegeX a lot', re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 18), match='I like RegeX a lot'>
```